# Looking for a Full Shade Vine to Grow in Zone 10 using a Trellis on Stucco

Tags: vines, shade

I'm completely stuck as to which vine would be ideal for a trellis on a stucco wall in full shade in South Florida (Zone 100. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!